# Draw on large image with java / BufferedImage / heap space

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to draw pointer on large image [around ~ `9984x9472 (94.6MP)`], for example: worldmap image. So far I've tried java `BufferedImage` and `Graphics2D` to do that. 
Now the problem is with heap space. From what I've read so far `BufferedImage` manipulates the image on memory, where for the above image needed space is around `9984x9472x4 = 378,273,792 byte`. That's a bummer. I tried to run following code with `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m` with **success** and `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` **failed**. Also all the suggestion points to increasing heap space. But I'm not sure how that's realistic on web application where user is viewing 5-10 of this kind of images which were drawn in realtime. Also there is a matter of concurrent user !

**Code to draw the image**

```
private void drawOnImage() {
    try {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/largeImage.jpg").getFile()));
        BufferedImage markerR = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/marker/R.png").getFile()));
        BufferedImage markerG = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/marker/G.png").getFile()));
        BufferedImage markerB = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/marker/B.png").getFile()));

        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D newImageG2d = newImage.createGraphics();
        newImageG2d.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);

        newImageG2d.drawImage(markerR, 0, originalImage.getHeight() / 2, null);
        newImageG2d.drawImage(markerG, (originalImage.getWidth() / 2 - markerG.getWidth() / 2), originalImage.getHeight() / 2, null);
        newImageG2d.drawImage(markerB, (originalImage.getWidth() - markerG.getWidth()), originalImage.getHeight() / 2, null);

        newImageG2d.dispose();

        File outputFile = File.createTempFile("newImage", ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", outputFileStream);
        outputFileStream.flush();

        System.out.println("Execution complete. Output file located: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also if anyone interested git: https://github.com/mamunsrdr/pwimage.git

**Now my question:** To do this kind of job `BufferedImage` doesn't look like the right candidate, or is it? Or is there any library that can do this without allocating large amount of memory and small footprint considering execution might be slower?

Comment: To spare some memory you should not keep 4 BufferedImages in memory at the same time. First read originalImage, draw it, keep its size and get rid of it. Then read R.png, draw it and dispose it. And so on.

Comment: tried https://github.com/mamunsrdr/pwimage/wiki/Stackoverflow-suggestion-1. Still not much improvement.